# Where do I find the variable name to use in a CQL statement

Tags: geoserver, layers, cql

For example I have been following tutorials and see examples such as
    DISJOINT(the_geom, POLYGON((-90 40, -90 45, -60 45, -60 40, -90 40)))

I have accessed some map data from sources such as data.gov.uk and loaded them into an instance of geoserver where it gives the option to run a CQL statement against the map, and I have run some very basic statements to confirm it actually works.

Some data sets are point data others are polygon data, how do I find out what to use in place of "the_geom" in the example above for any given map layer I have?

PS: link to tutorial http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

If you can administer the server just go into the "layer" panel to get the list of attribute names.

If not admin rights, you can still run a WFS DescribeFeatureType against that same layer and the returned XML schema will contain the attribute names as elements.

If you cannot do even that (because maybe WFS has been disabled), try to run a GetFeatureInfo in one of the various formats, the attribute names should show up there too (if you ask for the GML/GeoJSON variants, they should also contain the geometry)